# less is more? Is more less? I'm so confused

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, less, posix

When I first heard their names, I got really confused when  I tried to guess what these tools might do, I thought I'd misheard something.

What's the difference between `more` and `less`, i.e. why should I choose one over the other?
They both seem to do the same thing...

Also, why are they named like that in the first place?

Comment: Wait until you find out about `most`!  It's just like `more` and `less` but it supports colors too!

Comment: o_O you're joking right?

Comment: @Mehrdad [No](http://www.jedsoft.org/most/).

Comment: @new123456: lol `Why settle for less?`...

Comment: `less` is more than `more`!

Answer (score 84, accepted):

`more` is a basic pager, which allows you to scroll downwards, one page at a time. Only downwards.

`less` is also a pager, but has addition functionality to scroll upwards and downwards through the input, in addition to several other extensions.

So, yes. `less` is more, and `more` is less. Another common idiom (according to the [wiki entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix))) is "`less` is `more`, more or less." The name comes from the fact that the author (Mark Nudelman) essentially wanted a program that was "backwards more" -- The opposite of more, is `less`.

Comment: +1 cool, thanks. Any idea why `more` was named more, btw?

Comment: @Mehrdad All I have to go on is the wiki entry, which states "The name came from the joke of doing 'backwards more.'"

Comment: @Mehrdad I just realized I misread your comment-- I have no clue why `more` is called "more", but I would suspect that it's because all the program originally did was accept input and display `-- More --` at the bottom of the screen if there was more.

Comment: more came well before less, and was named for the simple purpose that it let you handle "more" output than would fit on screen.

Comment: True, more or less.

Comment: To add confusion...what about the 'most' pager program.

Comment: Which should you use?  It doesn't matter, `more` or `less`.

Answer (score 6):

I find `less` a bit more friendly than `more` because you can use the arrow keys to stroll through the file. `more` only scrolls screen by screen (by default).

Comment: ... And you can search with `/`

Answer (score 3):

Other that it allows more scrolling features, **less** also doesn't need to read the whole file, i.e. it loads files faster than **more**

Answer (score 2):

Another difference between `more` and `less`, is that `more` leaves the (last page of the) output on the shell, while `less` leaves the shell clean.

Sometimes you might prefer one over the other. For example, if you need to copy-paste from the file, `more` can be better. However, in other cases you might prefer the 'cleaner' approach of `less`.

Comment: Less's behavior on small inputs and its use of the alternate screen is configurable (`-F` and `-X` respectively).

Answer (score 0):

More or less they also work well together:

```
more * | less
```

This shows the contents of matching files along with the decorated matching file and directory names.