# Don't display filenames along with the contents when using "more"

Tags: linux, command-line, more

While displaying more than one file with `more`, I don't want to display filenames along with the contents.

I only need to display the contents of the file. Is there any way to escape the filenames?

Answer (score 2):

Trivial

```
cat file1 file2 file3 ... filen | more
```

Comment: http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html Useless use of cat award!

Comment: @Rob Really? `cat` concatenates the files. What else do you suggest?

Comment: I don't know how I missed the "Don't display filenames". I think I opened it in a new tab, forgot about it, came back to it and skimmed.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat file1 file2 | more
```

This is what you are looking for.

Comment: http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html Useless use of cat award!

Comment: I don't know how I missed the "Don't display filenames". I think I opened it in a new tab, forgot about it, came back to it and skimmed.

Answer (score -1):

`more "filename with space" "filenames" filename\ also\ with\ spaces and.one.more.file` is all you need, but you might consider using `less` instead of `more`. They say [less is more.](https://superuser.com/a/310138/97687)

Comment: That is not his question.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the right tool for the job. Especially when the tool is as widespread as `less`.

Comment: Missed the "Don't want to display filename" in the question. Not sure how.